# react native navigation between screens

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to use reactnavigation.org library and I have some issue with that. I have two types of navigation screens. Two screens are a registration and authorization. And others are regular app screens. Problem is that I can't render parent component App.js or other functionality to reload app from child component and thus change my screens block. Navigation between screens Run, History, Profile, OtherRunners works fine. Navigation between screens Main and Enter works fine. But if I need navigate from Run to Main, or from Enter to Run there is a problem.

**App.js**

```js
const App = () => {
    const Stack = createStackNavigator()
    const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator()
    const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false)
    async function getUserEmail(){
        if(await AsyncStorage.getItem('@email')){
            setLoggedIn(true)
        }else{
            setLoggedIn(false)
        }
    }
    getUserEmail()
    function MenuDraw(){
        return(
            <Drawer.Navigator
                drawerContentOptions={}
                drawerType={}
                drawerStyle={{}}
            >
                <Drawer.Screen
                    name="Run"
                    component={Run}
                    options={}
                />
                <Drawer.Screen
                    name="History"
                    component={History}
                    options={}
                />
                <Drawer.Screen
                    name="Profile"
                    component={Profile}
                    options={}
                />
                <Drawer.Screen
                    name="OtherRunners"
                    component={OtherRunners}
                    options={}
                />
                <Drawer.Screen
                    name="LogOut"
                    component={Run}
                    initialParams={{action: 'logout'}}
                    options={}
                />
            </Drawer.Navigator>
        )
    }
    function MyDrawer(){
        if(loggedIn){
            return(
                <Stack.Navigator
                    screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}
                    initialRouteName={"MenuDraw"}
                >
                    <Stack.Screen name="MenuDraw" component={MenuDraw}/>
                    <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={Details}/>
                </Stack.Navigator>
            )
        }else{
            return (
                <Stack.Navigator
                    screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}
                    initialRouteName={"Main"}
                >
                    <Stack.Screen name="MenuDraw" component={MenuDraw} />
                    <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={Details} />

                    <Stack.Screen name="Main" component={Main} />
                    <Stack.Screen name="Enter" component={Enter} />
                </Stack.Navigator>
            )
        }
    }
  return(
      <NavigationContainer>
          <MyDrawer/>
      </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
export default App;
```

I tried using reload app tools, but those wasn't help me. They are wasn't working. In this section of code which is below. On the Run screen.

**Run.js**

```js
const Run = ({navigation,route}) => {
    const clearStorage = async () => {
        await AsyncStorage.clear()
    }
    if(route.params){
        if(route.params.action === 'logout'){
            clearStorage()
            navigation.navigate("Main", {})
        }
    }
}
export default Run;
```

I'm trying to logout by cleaning the storage and navigate to Main screen. But it's not working on release mode. I've tried this, which is below.

**App.js**

```js
function MyDrawer(){
        if(loggedIn){
            return(
                <Stack.Navigator
                    screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}
                    initialRouteName={"MenuDraw"}
                >
                    <Stack.Screen name="MenuDraw" component={MenuDraw}/>
                    <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={Details}/>

++++                <Stack.Screen name="Main" component={Main} />
++++                <Stack.Screen name="Enter" component={Enter} />
                </Stack.Navigator>
            )
        }else{
            return (
                <Stack.Navigator
                    screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}
                    initialRouteName={"Main"}
                >
                    <Stack.Screen name="MenuDraw" component={MenuDraw} />
                    <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={Details} />

                    <Stack.Screen name="Main" component={Main} />
                    <Stack.Screen name="Enter" component={Enter} />
                </Stack.Navigator>
            )
        }
    }
```

Not working either way. How can I fix it? Can I render App.js component from child screens? Or perhaps I should create two screen blocks line

```js
<Stack.Screen name="MenuDraw" component={MenuDraw}/>
<Stack.Screen name="MenuRegister" component={MenuRegister}/>
```

and put all my screens by belongings to match section?

I need to logout from this section:
**App.js**

```js
some code

               <Drawer.Screen
                    name="LogOut"
                    component={Run}
                    initialParams={{action: 'logout'}}
                    options={}
                />
            </Drawer.Navigator>

some code
```

Comment: Does this help you out? https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow

Comment: No, it wasn't. It's easy when you need to render component in one file. But I have 
screen.js files which export to index.js file which exports to App.js file. And in last of them I have `const [login, setLogin] = useState()`. And If I can create some main `const` react variable. It's not render my App.js. I think so. I should somehow render App.js - parent component from child component for that action.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using useEffect hook, to get on the road? :-)

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const getUserEmail = async () => {
        if(await AsyncStorage.getItem('@email')){
            setLoggedIn(true)
        }else{
            setLoggedIn(false)
        }
    };
    getUserEmail();
  }, []);
```

Comment: I've tried `useEffect`, but it has meaning to render a component when I need to, depends of changed variable or state. If I could from the button reload react native app (expo) then I could use it. But I couldn't do that. I don't have those functionality, or I don't know one.

Comment: Alright so I am not 100% sure if I get you right, please correct if I am wrong. 
You want to return a _navigator_ depending on a state.
I think the trick is to only render the screens not an entire navigator. Maybe that helps: https://github.com/bithoven-dev/ReactNavigationAuthenticationFlowsWithHooks/blob/master/src/App.js

Comment: I have simplest way to explain my problem! Imagine you need change `const [logon, setLogin] = useState()` in App.js file (component) from Run.js child file (component) and render App.js after changing. Your child file Run.js exports to index.js file then export to App.js file. One condition: you can not use  JSX elements like - View, Text and so on. How would you do that? As I said before: if it was one file then there was no problem with that.

Comment: So if your App.js is holding the rendering logic I would still use useEffect to trigger a rerender on state change. As state is changed in a child component I would use a framework for state management like redux/ zustand or reacts buildin useContext/Provider pattern to get the info into App.js

Comment: Yes, you're right! ) But I thought there are simplest way to do that. Without using extra framework. After all, the process itself is very simple.

Comment: Sorry to say that I don't know of any other solution than that :-(

To avoid using a framework  you can still use context (https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html), although it feels a bit clunky.
However, I can really recommend to give Zustand a try though :-)